# ElasticSearch several search cases

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I have in MySQL the next structure:

1. Table groups - `id`, `title`, `user_id`
2. Table keywords - `id`, `title`
3. Table group_keyword - `group_id`, `keyword_id`

I do search with 5 cases:

1. Full match by group title `title = "keyword"`
2. Full match by keyword title `title = "keyword"`
3. Partial match by group title `title like "keyword%"`
4. Partial match by group title `title like "%keyword%"`
5. Partial match by keyword title `title like "%keyword%"`

These queries combine into one query. For each subquery it appends a column called `priority`, on which sorting takes place.

My question is: How I should configure ElasticSearch to do the above cases or how I should build queries to Elastic to get the results? I ask, because this query is very slow on Mysql, we did many optimizations, added indexes, split tables and etc, all optimization results are temporary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your keyword field to be analyzed or not ?
Does it have to be 5 DIFFERENT cases ?

You have to establish which type of possible queries you want.

Because the wildcard query :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

manages the search for all the 5 cases (for non analyzed fields though which means that keyword sub-terms are not tokenized, ES searches the keyword attribute using the defalt analyzer which splits word using simple blanks unless you specify custom analyzer).

If you want something more flexible and performance is not an issue (analyzed attribute) then you can use a ngram analysis :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

This one tokenizes your sub-terms, which means it breaks it in multiple chars depending on your ngram configuration.

Your document mapping should of course specify the anlyser in each case :

wildcard research ==> not_analyzed

ngram research ==>ngram

PS: pay attention while browsing the ES documentation. ES version specification is very important since ther is a lot of depreciation between versions :). Select the major version of your installation in the right, then browse.